# How can I jump really high in Mario Kart 64?

Tags: mario-kart-64

Some levels, such as Toad's turn pike and the train level, have big shortcuts if you can jump over a large wall.

How can I jump over walls in Mario Kart 64?

Update: the rainbow road jump does not count since it can only be done in a specific place and this is due to the map containing a huge down hill part in the level.

Comment: Does the Rainbow Road jump count? In terms of travel, it's pretty high, but the wall to clear isn't actually tall on its own.

Comment: @Grace: updated the question

Comment: This works in Choco Mountain as well.  You can jump up the side of the cliff to the higher track just before going around the big loop surrounding a pond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use other drivers as "spring". That at least worked for when starting a race from last position - pushing A just in time for a speed start, then pushing R to jump *on* the driver in front of me, which causes my to bounce in front of the field. I guess this can also be achieved with a mushroom when another driver is in a good position.

Answer (score 2):

One way I have figured out to do this is to be someone fairly light weight (e.g. Toad or Yoshi), then get a buddy to play as a heavy-weight (e.g. Donkey Kong). Next, have them line up right near the wall, facing towards it. Now you will need a mushroom and to line up behind them. Once you are lined up, you stand a little behind them such that the mushroom will give you enough power to run into them, normally causing your character to spin out. Right as you hit them, though, press the R button to jump. If timed correctly, this will launch you fairly high up, enough to jump over most walls.

If you time it correctly, you might even be able to do this without organizing with a buddy, since this does work while the heavy-weight is driving. It just might be really hard to line up correctly while both of you are driving.

Comment: It can be done with out the the heavy-weight.  It is mostly a question of timing and having mushrooms (at least for the train level).  Having the gold mushroom or a star is even better.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about those two shortcuts, but the shortcut in Wario Stadium requires you to hop just as you hit the wall.  When you time it correctly, you can jump up and over the wall.

Here is a [video showing the Wario Stadium shortcut](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=soQCw2tpw7M).

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wmbYdM3oSYo&feature=related) shows a number of different glitch / shortcuts.  Toad's Turnpike is at 3:49, but it appears to be more of a glitch with the texture seams than an actual jump over the wall.

Comment: This is more of a level specific answer... I'm looking for a way to do this on any level.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way is to use power sliding to boost and then jump.  While it is fairly easy to get the sliding boost around corners, it actually can be done at any time.  The basic technique is ([source](http://www.neoseeker.com/Games/cheats/N64/mario_kart_64.html))

> Slide around a turn as normally (with
>   the R button), but if you flick the
>   analog stick to the left and back to
>   the right again (or vice versa), your
>   smoke trail will turn yellow, and if
>   you flick it again (all while holding
>   R), it will turn red -- at which point
>   you let go of the R button and you'll
>   get approximately a 10km/hr speed
>   burst.

Comment: How high do you jump? Is it higher than a normal jump? Do you need to run into another player before you jump, like in my answer? Or can it be done anywhere anytime?